# AMO in c# project

Tags: c#, sql, ssas

I am building and deploying a SSAS cubes using AMO.

I need the complete object model for AMO as an XSD (in schema form).

I currently have built a schema by hand based on things that I need, but I'm afraid there would be elements that will come up during development time later on that will cause the upstream process that fills an XML file based on the XSD.

I've googled and binged without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx)